# Do javascript code blocks run atomically relative to the single thread?

Tags: javascript, typescript, concurrency, atomic, single-threaded

When I am developing in Typescript and I have a variable:

`const fn: undefined | () => void`

and write this:

```
...
if (!fn)
    return;
setTimeout(() => fn(), 0);
...
```

Typescript will complain, stating that the `fn` object could be undefined inside the `setTimeout`, as it is going to be executed asynchronously and by the time it does, the `fn` function might be indeed undefined and so it cannot be invoked as a function.

So I have to do something like this:

```
...
setTimeout(() => {
 if (!fn)
    return;
 fn();
}
, 0);
...
```

but at what level is the atomicity of statements achieved?

I mean even if I check that `fn` is not `undefined` in the `if` how can I be sure that it will still not be undefined by the statement `fn()`. At which level does javascript provide this "atomicity" / "concurrency"?

Comment: If you put the `setTimeout(() => fn(), 0);` into an `else` block, TS should stop complaining as you will be sure that `fn()` is defined when it is called be `setTimeout()`

Comment: @secan Yes but why? Does it have to do with the call stack ?

Comment: I can't see typescript complaining in this little fiddle: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?allowJs=true&target=6&ts=4.1.5#code/LAKAZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQARiUgFASlQb1FWNRhQGc500BeVXVGgPlIqQBsBTAOnaQHMsAIgAmKTkJwBuIiQRh6AQjBQcskiQBOnOBE1QZIdanI6AKggC2nJBDhYGzargA0qAAzTQAX1CgM2NJAA (unless I've got the TS settings wrong in the snippet?)

Comment: @NickParsons That's because you haven't stated that ```fn``` can also be undefined. Try this: ```
function foo() {
    let fn: undefined | (() => void) = () => console.log('not undefined');
    if (!fn){
        fn = undefined;
        return;
    }
    setTimeout(() => fn(), 0);
}

foo();
```

Comment: @but-why ah I see, thanks. If you watch the first 11min of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0&t=1036s&ab_channel=JSConf) video it might help you answer the atomicity part of your question